# How to set my proxy list in order and not in random?

Tags: php

I am beginner on using PHP. How to make start at 1 till the end? Cause I'm getting a random proxy every request. Thank you for helping!

```
$proxylist = file("proxies.txt");
$proxys= $proxylist[rand(0, count($proxylist) - 1)];
$proxy = explode(":", $proxys);
$proxydes = $proxy[0];
$port = $proxy[1];
$proxyyyys = "".$proxydes.":".$port."";
echo $proxyyyys;
```

Comment: Why do you use a random function then, if you don't want it random?

Comment: I only know how to use random function, but the code of "in order function" that is I don't know